# PySpark: create column based on value and dictionary in columns

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapping

I have a PySpark dataframe with values and dictionaries that provide a textual mapping for the values.
Not every row has the same dictionary and the values can vary too.

```
| value    | dict                                           | 
| -------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| 1        | {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}                 |
| 2        | {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}                 |
| 0        | {"0": "Another text A", "1": "Another text B"} |
```

I want to make a "status" column that contains the right mapping.

```
| value    | dict                             | status   |
| -------- | -------------------------------  | -------- |
| 1        | {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}   | Text A   |
| 2        | {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}   | Text B   |
| 0        | {"0": "Other A", "1": "Other B"} | Other A  |
```

I have tried this code:

```
df.withColumn("status", F.col("dict").getItem(F.col("value"))
```

This code does not work. With a hard coded value, like "2", the same code does provide an output, but of course not the right one:

```
df.withColumn("status", F.col("dict").getItem("2"))
```

Could someone help me with getting the right mapped value in the status column?

EDIT: my code did work, except for the fact that my "value" was a double and the keys in dict are strings. When casting the column from double to int to string, the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents

1. Create the dataframe by reading from CSV or any other source (in my case it is just static data)

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.types import *

    data = [
    (1 , {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}),
    (2 , {"1": "Text A", "2": "Text B"}),
    (0 , {"0": "Another text A", "1": "Another text B"} )
    ]


    schema = StructType([
                        StructField("ID",StringType(),True),
                        StructField("Dictionary",MapType(StringType(),StringType()),True),
                        ])

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)
    df.show(truncate=False)
   ```
2. Then directly extract the dictionary value based on the id as a key.

   ```
   df.withColumn('extract',df.Dictionary[df.ID]).show(truncate=False)
   ```

Check the below image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This does work indeed. After evaluation, I see that my original code should work too. My problem was that value (ID in your case) was a double and in the mapping it was a string.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Medium').master('local[1]').getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.format('csv').option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").load("/Users/dshanmugam/Desktop/ss.csv")
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("1", StringType(), True)
    ])


    def return_value(data):
        key = data.split('-')[0]
        value = json.loads(data.split('-')[1])[key]
        return value

    returnVal = udf(return_value)
    df_new = df.withColumn("newCol",concat_ws("-",col("value"),col("dict"))).withColumn("result",returnVal(col("newCol")))
    df_new.select(["value","result"]).show(10,False)
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------+
|value|result        |
+-----+--------------+
|1    |Text A        |
|2    |Text B        |
|0    |Another text A|
+-----+--------------+
```

I am using UDF. You can try with some other options if performance is a concern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately performance is a concern so UDF won't be the solution for me.

Comment: Oh okay!! You can try vectorizing with Pandas UDF so that it can improve performance.